# Proofs of Taylor-series expansions

Tags: sequences-and-series

For differentiable functions, one would think that the values of successive derivatives at a single point are so “very local” properties of a function,  that they cannot possibly determine its values at other points lying “very far away”. 
As is well-known,  for many useful functions this is not so, as revealed by the Taylor-series expansion theorem,  of  functions exponential, trigonometric, logarithmic etc.

My problem is that in all proofs I know of, this overwhelmingly wonderful & miraculous phenomenon is seemingly extinguished by a rather dry technical manoeuver: by repeated application of the mean-value theorem, for all x the remainder is bounded by something tending to zero as n tends to infinity,  so the expansion is valid.

I wonder, where has the “miracle-point” gone? Can someone give an intuitive explanation that captures the essence of these “by-a-single-point-uniquely -determinable” functions?

Comment: The passage from local to global is done by using some global condition. For example, for $\sin$ you know that its derivative is bounded and then the $n!$ overpowers the $(\theta-0)^n$ for all $\theta\in[-R,R]$. For $e^x$ on the interval $[-R,R]$ you know that the $n!$ outweighs the factor $e^{\theta}(\theta-0)^n$ for all $\theta\in[-R,R]$. It is always some condition that holds for all $\theta$. The sequence of derivatives at a single point alone [is not enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem).

Comment: The classes of functions in which the derivatives at a point determines the function (within the class) are called [quasi-analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-analytic_function) classes of functions. This generalizes the class of [analytic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function), which among other properties have the property that you were talking about (being determined by their derivatives at a point). $e^x,\sin(x)$ are analytic functions and the class of analytic functions is quasi-analytic.